# PowerShell - Download files with WebDAV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, webdav

I want to use PowerShell with WebDAV (https) to download multiple files from a folder. The name from the download files is unknown. So my plan is to download all files from this folder and create a cleaning job at the server.

At the moment I´m searching for a good PowerShell with WebDAV example. Does anybody know a good example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't try it but do you just test [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class?

```
PS > $source = "http://www.unsite.fr/untruc.zip"
PS > $destination = "c:\temp\untruc.zip" 
PS >
PS >$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
PS >$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

----Edited------
Do you try to dig into ADODB.stream com object as you cansee in : "[PowerShell : Upload file to WebDav Server](http://www.vnext.be/category/powershell/)"

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The problem with the WebClient is that I don´t know the file names. So I think WebDAV is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://amarchuk.blogspot.com/2011/10/heres-c-webdav-client-that-works-with.html

You can store it as cs file, then call add-type to add it to powershell and from there on client.GetListItems to get names and then download all files recursively.